# VBA Excel: Copying across sheets using alphanumeric range vs cells

Tags: vba, excel

Bit of a bizarre title, I'll explain what I'm asking.

The use of `.Range("A1:B2").copy` vs using `.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(2, 2)).copy`.

Both will work, but *only* when I'm on the actual sheet. If I'm on a different sheet when the macro gets called, then only the alphanumeric range will work.

Actual code in question:

```
CurrentExtractSheet.Range("A2: AR" & (CurrentExtractCount + 1)).Copy
PreviousExtractSheet.Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

vs

```
CurrentExtractSheet.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(CurrentExtractCount + 1, 45)).Copy
PreviousExtractSheet.Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

So what I'm asking is there any way to work around this issue (I prefer using the `Cells` method rather than alphanumeric ranges)? Does `Cells` require an activesheet first (also which I don't particularly like)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to set CurrentExtractSheet to be the ActiveSheet, but you do need to include it with your Cells command as so...

```
CurrentExtractSheet.Range(CurrentExtractSheet.Cells(2, 1), CurrentExtractSheet.Cells(CurrentExtractCount + 1, 45)).Copy
```

or

```
With CurrentExtractSheet
 .Range(.Cells(2, 1),.Cells(CurrentExtractCount + 1, 45)).Copy
End With
```

Answer (score 3):

When doing `Cells(x,y)` without specifying a sheet, your are in fact referening to the activesheet.

So, `CurrentExtractSheet.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(CurrentExtractCount + 1, 45))` is equivalent to `CurrentExtractSheet.Range(Activesheet.Cells(2, 1), Activesheet.Cells(CurrentExtractCount + 1, 45))`

When `CurrentExtractSheet` is not the active sheet it fails.

There are several ways to avoid this error

```
With CurrentExtractSheet
    Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(CurrentExtractCount + 1, 45)) ...
End With
```

Note, when you specify the sheets for the two `.Cells` references you don't need to qualift `Range`

Another otpion

```
CurrentExtractSheet.Cells(2, 1).Resize(CurrentExtractCount, 45) ...
```